# Meteor - image in public directory of one app is available in a different app - how come?

Tags: meteor

So I am running two meteor apps on my machine at the moment.  One is running on port 3000 and the other is running on port 4000.  There is an image in the `public/` directory of the app running on port 4000, and it is available from the other app, which is running on port 3000.  This seems to me like it shouldn't happen.

I have double-checked, and I only have one copy of the image - in the public directory of only the app running on port 4000..  However, both of the following URLs display the image:

```
localhost:3000/image.png
localhost:4000/image.png
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Was it ever in the other project? If so, could it just be cached? If you are using chrome, what happens if you check the URL in incognito mode?

Comment: In incognito mode the image doesn't show up.  It must have been the cache.  I had previously been running the same two apps, but with the ports reversed, so that must have been the problem.

Comment: Great suggestion to use incognito mode to check.  I was thinking some kind of nginx proxy issue.